# Upload Excel Range to Server with OfficeJS Add-In

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I'm trying to figure out a way to upload an excel range to server. I want to include all formatting and formulas. I know there are ways to individually upload formatting paremters but I would like to avoid having to indivually maintain and update each of these.

I would like to find a way to get the copied data from a function similar to this

```
// Copy a range, omitting the blank cells so existing data is not overwritten in those cells.
    otherSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(
      range,
      Excel.RangeCopyType.all,
      true, // skipBlanks
      false
    ); // transpose
```

I have also tried selecting a range and copying and paste, however it seems that there are security features in place to prevent me from doing so. I'm also open to other approaches.